# Error when trying to store an array in ScriptDb

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an array of objects that is created by my script and I am trying to copy that array into a new array and then store it in scriptDb using the following function:

```
function copyAndStore (currentArray) {
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var copyArray = [];
  for (var i in currentArray) {
    copyArray.push(currentArray[i]);
  }
  var id = db.save(copyArray);
  return id;
}
```

It copies everything properly but when it gets to `var id = db.save(copyArray);` I get the error: `Invalid argument. Expected a javascript map object.`

Does ScriptDb have issues with storing arrays? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What's in `currentArray`?

Comment: currentArray is an array of objects that contain info and stats about different departments (name, #members, monthly visits, etc).

Comment: Just be sure you don't try to store native Date objects. That can cause silent and ambiguous errors.

Comment: @Jonathon makes a good point. If you do end up needing to store `Date` objects, read over [the tips in the ScriptDB documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb#dates) to avoid problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Thomas said, you can save an array in a map object.

You don't need to perform a copy operation before putting an object into the ScriptDB, either. You could save your array by simply `db.save({myArray})`, and remember the ID.

Here's some minimalist code to demonstrate. I'm showing two ways to retrieve your saved array - one by ID, which seems to be the way you were planning to, but also a second way using a "key" value for a query. If you expect to retrieve the contents of ScriptDB in a later run of your code, this approach eliminates the need to somehow remember the ID of the stored array.

```
function saveArray (currentArray) {
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  return db.save({type: "savedArray", data:currentArray}).getId();
}

function loadArrayById (id) {
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  return db.load(id).data;
}

function loadArrayByType () {
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var result = db.query({type: "savedArray"});
  if (result.hasNext()) {
    return result.next().data;
  }
  else {
    return [];
  }
}

function test() {
  var arr = ['this','is','a','test'];
  var savedId = saveArray( arr );
  var loaded1 = loadArrayById( savedId );
  var loaded2 = loadArrayByType();
  debugger;  // pause if running debugger
}
```

Here's what you'll see at the debugger pause:

[image: Screenshot of debugger]

Note that by using the map tag `data` to pull the array from the saved object, both `loaded1` and `loaded2` are identical to the source array `arr`.

Comment: +1 for debugger. I tend to scatter void(0) throughout and add/remove breaks to them.

Answer (score 1):

`ScriptDb` only stores map objects. You could however store a map that contains an array!

You can use arrays to save several objects in a single call using `db.saveBatch`.

Comment: sorry I'm new to this so how would I create a map that contains the array i want to store?

I use `db.saveBatch` earlier in my script to store the raw data about departments from a spreadsheet.

Comment: You just need to define an object like this `var myObj = {array:YOUR_ARRAY,id:SOME_IDENTIFIER};` where you provide some identifier so that you can retrieve it later. Then you can just `db.save(myObj);`