# Debugger fails with "This operation is not supported from a callback function."

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-apps-script, callback

I have noticed that GAS's debugger cannot handle breakpoints in callback functions. This simple script works fine if run, but if a breakpoint is set at the line `return element`, the debugger throws an error `This operation is not supported from a callback function.` Here is the test function:

```
function callbackTest() {

  var myArray = [1,2,3];

  var output = myArray.map(function(a){
    return a;
  });

  Logger.log(output);
}
```

This also fails if a breakpoint is put at the same place:

```
function callbackTest() {

  var myArray = [1,2,3];
  var output = myArray.map(testFunc);
  Logger.log(output);

}

function testFunc(a) {
    return a;
}
```

I had [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32463402/google-scripts-basic-javascript-issue-fixed-by-debugger) a few days ago about the GAS debugger, but this doesn't seem (to me) to be related. Please feel free to demonstrate that I am wrong!

Comment: So what are you asking here? How to debug callbacks?

Comment: Yes. I'm admittedly a novice, but I haven't found any resources suggesting that there is some special process for debugging non-async callbacks. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you've just hit a limitation in the script editor that you're not going to get around, just throw a load of Logger.log()'s at it. I've noticed that the script editor avoids displaying any functions that need callbacks in the auto-complete.

Comment: That makes sense, but it was surprising to me to see that. Is it common for editors to have such serious limitations like this? Obviously I can work around it, but it really makes debugging a pain.

Comment: This has been reported as [Issue 4662](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4662). Star it, etc.

Comment: @Mogsdad, if you want to answer the question I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Someone beat me to it! There is an answer covering this on another question, so it would be best to just duplicate this one.