# Track how many times a function is used

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I'm using a function (`AGR_PROD`) to add a row in Google Spreadsheets, and I need to count the times I use `AGR_PROD` function so later on I can delete the times I added these rows with another function (`EraseInfo`). So I have a variable called `numrows` to have as a counter.

```
var numrows = 0;
function AGR_PROD() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   spreadsheet.getRange('12:12').activate();
   spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastRow(), 1);
   spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
   spreadsheet.getRange('C13').activate();
   spreadsheet.getRange('C12:D12').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
   SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);

  numrows = numrows +1;
  Logger.log(numrows)
  return numrows;
};
```

The following code is for the **erase** function, so I'm trying to pass it the `numrows` variable.

```
function EraseInfo(numrows) {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('הצעת מחיר');
   sheet.getRange('B2:B8').clearContent();
   sheet.getRange('F1:F3').clearContent();
   Logger.log(numrows)
   sheet.deleteRows(501, numrows)
   numrows = 0;
}
```

The `Logger` is just for debugging purposes, but I get an **Cannot find method deleteRows(number,(class)). (line 20, file "macros")**.

Comment: Do you mind giving the contents of your undefined error?

Comment: What do you mean? The whole output line of error?

Comment: Yes. I need to know what it says.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the original code and the error I get is this: Cannot find method deleteRows(number,(class)). (line 20, file "macros")

Answer (score 1):

Since you're declaring `numrows` as a global variable, you don't need to pass it to the `EraseInfo` function. So no need to include `numrows` as a parameter for `EraseInfo`.

```
function EraseInfo() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('הצעת מחיר');
   sheet.getRange('B2:B8').clearContent();
   sheet.getRange('F1:F3').clearContent();
   Logger.log(numrows)
   sheet.deleteRows(501, numrows)
   numrows = 0;
}
```

Also check out: [Global variables in Google Script (spreadsheet)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17375386/5037430)

You might want to use [Properties Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24749707/5037430) as you can use these as a kind of persistent global variable.

Comment: Sorry, I coppied the unmodified code, I edited the original code now.

Comment: Oh, right, good call, I had modified it, I originally put the `numrows` as parameter because the `DeleteRows` function doesn't get the amount of times I used the `AGR_PROD` function. So it displays this error: Those rows are out of bounds. (line 20, file "macros")

Comment: I don't think I can help with this new error. But you could ask this in another question with more context about the new error and what have you tried to solve this.

Comment: Well, all I really need to know is why the `EraseInfo()` function does'nt get the `numrows` variable from the `AGR_PROD()` function. I have tried your suggestion and giving the variable `numrows` different names. I'm new to coding, I don't know what is wrong with the syntax.

Comment: > Global variables in GAS are static - you can't update them and expect them to retain their values.

So you might need to use the [Properties Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24749707/5037430).