# How to query an array value from scriptDB?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to access a global variable from a main function to a handler function using scriptDb.
Following the [documentation instructions][1], I create a piece of code similar to this:

```
function showList(arrayList) {
   Logger.log("arrayList argument value = " + arrayList);
      var arrayToUse = {
        arrayName: 'theses',
        arrayValue: arrayList,
    };
    var record = db.save(arrayToUse);
    var scriptDbObject = db.query({arrayName: 'theses'});
    var arrayList = scriptDbObject.arrayValue;
    Logger.log("ShowList arrayList query value = " + arrayList);
    }
```

But when I try to query the inserted item, It doesn't work:

![enter image description here][2]

The argument `arrayList` is OK (as the log shows).

I also tried this other code, **following as similar as I could** [this stackoverflow question][3]:

```
function showList(arrayList) {
  Logger.log("arrayList argument value = " + arrayList);
  var record = db.save({arrayName: "savedArray", arrayValue: arrayList});
  var result = db.query({arrayName: 'thesesRequests'});
  if (result.hasNext()) {
    arrayList = result.next().data;
    }
  else {
    arrayList ["empty array", "empty", "array"];
  }
    Logger.log("ShowList arrayList query value = " + arrayList);
```

And I got the same `undefined` message.

What is going wrong here?
[1]: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/script-db/
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CpyY.png
[3]: [Error when trying to store an array in ScriptDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033802/error-when-trying-to-store-an-array-in-scriptdb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first go of yours was on the mark, except that when u do a query you need to use the next() operator on the result to get the actual dbResult entry:

```
function showList(arrayList) {
   Logger.log("arrayList argument value = " + arrayList);
      var arrayToUse = {
        arrayName: 'theses',
        arrayValue: arrayList,
    };
    var record = db.save(arrayToUse);
    var scriptDbObject = db.query({arrayName: 'theses'});
    if (scriptDbObject.hasNext()) {
      var dbItem = scriptDbObject.next();
      var dbArrayList = dbItem.arrayValue 
      Logger.log("ShowList arrayList query value = " + dbArrayList);
    }
 }
```